# Active Directory groups and roles

Tags: azure-active-directory

I'm trying to incorporate Azure Active Directory to a project, ultimately I'm supposed to have three layers of roles and permissions

1- Divisions
2- Locations
3- Roles

Scenarios:

Scenario 1:
A user can be a manager in location 1 in Div 0, but a regular employee in location 2 in Div 0 too

Scenario 2:
A user can be an admin in Div 1 which means he will be able to access all locations that are a member of Div 1

Scenario 3:
Div 0 is a group, locations are groups nested inside Div 0, roles are the types of roles given to users (the pages they're able to access based on which location and division they're in)

When they're assigned and everything checks out, I'm not sure what's the best way to handle it in C# MVC app.

Not sure if what I'm trying to do makes any sense or is confusing.

Help is extremely appreciated.

Comment: I assume that you wanna a user role management system which could make web pages in different locations in different divisions have restrict to different users. I haven't found a better solution in azure ad to achieve this than you create a custom role assignment web page and web page management web page. I mean that from my point of view, it's better to achieve your feature by your program because it is more scalable。

Comment: @Tiny-wa yes I agree with you, this is correct, I read somewhere that someone had problems with admin users who had access to all groups in AD, the token became very long as it stored all these claims, that's why I'm a bit skeptical about AD or not sure what's the best practice here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As what discussed in comment, I think the best way to solve your problem is creating a custom role assignment web page and page management web page so that it will be the most suitable system for your requirement and it is more scalable.